# Is a product of infinite subsets of $\Bbb C_p$ Zariski dense in $\Bbb C_p^2$?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, p-adic-number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, zariski-topology

Consider the $p$-adic number field $\mathbb Q_p$. Let $\mathbb C_p:=\widehat{\bar{\mathbb Q}_p}$ with maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$.

Then any infinite subset $S \subset \mathfrak m$ is Zariski-dense in $\mathfrak{m}$.

Now consider a subset $T=T_1 \times T_2 \subset \mathbb C_p \times \mathbb C_p=\mathbb C_p^2$, where both $T_1$ and $T_2$ are infinite.

> Is the infinite set $T$ a zariski-dense in $\mathbb C_p \times \mathbb C_p$ ?

---

We know that Zariski closure of a set is the intersection of the "zero-sets" of all polynomials vanishing on it. So Zariski closure $\bar T$ is equal to affine $2$-space $\mathbb C_p^2$ if and only if any polynomial vanishing on $T$ vanishes on $\mathbb C_p^2$. So we can think of $\bar T$ as the union of finitely many varieties. Then choose $V$ to be an irreducible component of $\bar T$ containing infinitely many points of $T$. Since $V$ is infinite, it is of positive dimension. So $\text{dim}(V)=1$ or $2$.

We have to show $\text{dim}(V) \neq 1$, in that case, $\text{dim}(V)=2$ and $V=\mathbb C_p^2=\bar T$.

Can you help me to conclude the proof ? Am I going into right direction ?

Thanks

Comment: If $f(x,y)\in K[x,y]$ is not the zero polynomial then $f(x,y)=\sum_{n=0}^N f_n(x)y^n$ with $f_n\in K[x]$, one of the $f_n$, say $f_k$, is not the zero polynomial.

$f_k$ has finitely many zeros so there is some $t_1\in T_1$ such that $f_k(t_1)\ne 0$.

Then $f(t_1,y)\in K[y]$ is not the zero polynomial. It has finitely many zeros so there is some $t_2\in T_2$ such that $f(t_1,t_2)\ne 0$.

Comment: @reuns, I didn't get quite well. Are saying the irreducible component $V$ of $\bar{T}$ is not vanishing for any nonzero polynomial ? Does it mean $\text{dim}(V) \neq 1$ ? Can you please explain what you want to mean ?

Comment: As a word of caution, appealing to the product topology does *not* work, since the Zariski topology on a product of varieties is not the product topology. In fact, it's a finer topology, so closures can be smaller; if it were a coarser topology then the argument would still work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an answer tying together all of the discussion here on this page.

---

**Proof your set is dense**

Let $K$ be an infinite field. Let $T_1,T_2\subset K$ be infinite subsets. Let $T=T_1\times T_2\subset K^2$. Then $T$ is dense in $K^2$ when $K$ is equipped with the Zariski topology. To prove this, we show that there is no non-zero polynomial in $K[x,y]$ which vanishes on $T$.

Suppose $f(x,y)$ vanishes on $T$. Without loss of generality, $f$ is of positive degree $d$ in $y$. Write $f(x,y)=\sum_{i=0}^d f_i(x)y^i$ with $d>0$ and $f_d(x)\neq 0$. Since $T_1$ is infinite and $f_d(x)$ has only finitely many roots, $f_d(x)$ cannot vanish on all of $K$ and therefore there is an $x_1\in T_1$ such that $f_d(x_1)\neq 0$. Therefore $f(x_1,y)$ is a polynomial in $y$ of degree $d$ which must vanish on the infinite set $\{x_1\}\times T_2$, contradiction.

---

**Commentary on other solution methods**

Note that one cannot appeal to an argument such as ["the product of dense sets is dense in the product"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/623314/cartesian-product-and-closure/623336#623336) because the Zariski topology on a product is not the product of the Zariski topologies ([ref 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1911215/zariski-topology-finer-than-product-topology), [ref 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4543881/zariski-topology-in-the-product-of-algebraic-varieties), [ref 3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4461189/zariski-topology-of-mathbbc-times-mathbbc-is-finer-than-the-product-top)).

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: Consider an infinite subset $T=\{(a_i,b_i)~|~a_i,b_i \in \bar{\mathbb Q}_p\}$, where $a_i \neq a_{i+1}$ and $b_i \neq b_{i+1},~i \in \mathbb N$. That is, $T$ contains infinitely many pairs of $\bar{\mathbb Q}_p^2$. In this case, $T$ is not necessarily product of two infinite sets as in the above question. My intuition says $T$ is also Zariski dense in $\bar{\mathbb Q}_p^2$. Can you please hint how to prove it ? Thanks

Comment: @ANG this is not true: $\{(1,1),(2,2),\cdots\}\subset V(x-y)$, for instance.

Comment: ok. But then $\{(1,1),(2,2), \cdots \} \subset V(x-y)$ is also true for the above case as well, which you answered to be dense. Am I reading something wrong ? What is the difference here in this case ? I just want to know, when is an infinite subset $T$ of $\bar{\mathbb Q}_p^2$ is Zariski dense in it ? You gave a positive answer when $T$ can be written as carteisan product of two infinite sets. Are there other possibilities of $T$ ? Thanks

Comment: @ANG the copy of the integers embedded diagonally is not a product of two infinite sets! The proper closed subsets of $k^2$ with the Zariski topology are finite unions of points and curves. If your infinite set cannot be contained in a finite unions of curves, it is dense.

Comment: great comment. I think I got it now. The main point is that "if an infinite subset of $k^2$ can not be written as a union of finitely many curves, then it will be dense in Zariski topology". By the way, I don't think $\{(1,1),(2,2), \cdots \}$ are the only points in the set $T=\{(a,b)~|~a,b \in \bar{\mathbb Q}_p \}$. In fact, $T$ contains infinitely many other points as well. I think it is not obvious whether we can write $T$ as a union of finitely many curves. I might make few other comments, because I need help. Thanks a lot

Comment: @ANG You have stated things imprecisely: $\{(a,a)\mid a\in\Bbb Z_{\geq 0}\}$ is not a union of finitely many curves, but it's **contained in a union of finitely many curves**: the single curve $V(x-y)$, for instance. The point is that a set satisfying your description of infinitely many distinct points in $k^2$ cannot be judged to be dense without knowing more about it. If you have further issues, please ask a new question so appropriate space can be given to resolve all of your queries (600 characters in the comments is a bit limiting).

Comment: It is alright. Thanks for your help

Comment: If we had $T=T_1 \times T_2 \times T_3$, all $T_i$ are infinite, then your argument doesn't work because in that case we need to consider a polynomial $f(x,y,z) \in K[x,y,z]$. Then it can be written as $f(x,y,z)=\sum \alpha(x,y)z^n \in K[z]$. But $\alpha(x,y)$ might have infinitely many roots on $T_1 \times T_2$. So your argument is not applicable for higher products. Am I right ?

Comment: No. It is easy to extend the argument by induction: if we know that a product of $n$ dense sets $T_1,\cdots,T_n\subset K$ is dense in $K^n$, then any nonzero polynomial $f\in K[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$ must have some point $t\in\prod T_i$ so that $f(t)\neq 0$. So the same strategy in the post will show that a polynomial vanishing on a product of $n+1$ dense subsets in $K^{n+1}$ must be the zero polynomial, or that this product is again dense. Also, getting asked trivial follow-up questions two months later is not fun- the more you do it, the less likely I (or anyone else on MSE) is to respond to you.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, I got stuck with the fact that multivariable polynomial have infinitely many roots over $K$. This is why I ask this comment. But I forgot that we already proved $T_1 \times T_2$ is dense, and hence we can use it. Anyway, I give $+1$ for not choosing the other way (in your last sentence).